# Generic method for Similar Objects

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

C# 4.0
If i have N classes(Entities) with completely the same properties, they don’t have any common interface or any common inheritance
I want to have method to be able to pass any of their instances, without copy any properties from one object to another.
I think there should be a couple of ways of doing this in .NET 4.0.

e.g somehow using var or dynamik keywords or using generic types.
May be something like that:

```
    public void MyMethod<MyType>(AnyType myInstance)
    {
        Type myType = typeof(T);
        myInstance = myInstance as myType;

        AppendToFile(myInstance.Field1);
        AppendToFile(myInstance.Field2);
    }
```

Now i am investigating that, may be someone have any ideas about that.

Comment: Altho it's possible, as others have pointed out, I'll argue that it's still really neater to make them share an interface. If the code is somehow not yours, but the classes are partial (as is the case with the DBML classes), you can create partial classes only to specify interface implementation. `public partial class ClassA : IInterface { } public partial class ClassB : IInterface {}`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to or can't  derive them or add an interface, then you will have to use `dynamic`

I believe this will do it, assuming AppendToFile takes dynamic parameters or the Field1 and Field2 are always the same types.

```
public void MyMethod(dynamic myInstance)
{
    AppendToFile(myInstance.Field1);
    AppendToFile(myInstance.Field2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to change the classes to just implement the interface.

Another approach would be to create the interface that you desire, and then create a default implementation of the interface that just wraps a dynamic object and implements the interface. Then any methods in this default implementation just become pass-throughs to the underlying dynamic.

This would allow you to consistently work with the IMyInterface interface instead of working with the dynamics directly.

For example:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
      string Field1 { get; }
      string Field2 { get; }
}

public class MyDefaultInterface : IMyInterface
{
      private Dynamic _dynamic;
      public MyDefaultInterface(dynamic target)
      {
          _dynamic = target;
      }
      public string Field1 { get { return _dynamic.Field1; } }
      public string Field2 { get { return _dynamic.Field2; } }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to use `dynamic`, you can use this:

```
public void MyMethod(dynamic myInstance)
{
    AppendToFile(myInstance.Field1); //note: you will get no intellisense support
    AppendToFile(myInstance.Field2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use reflection (not .NET 4.0 specific):

```
object field1Value = myType.GetField("Field1").GetValue(myInstance);
```

I have to ask, is it not possible to change the classes to implement the same interface?